# How to access a dataset on a distant worker node from the master node?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have on my local network two virtual machines that are connected as Master and Slave nodes in an Spark environment.
if I do on the worker `VM1`

```
Dataset<Row> recordsDF = spark.createDataFrame(records, Record.class);
recordsDF.createOrReplaceTempView("records");
```

and on the master `VM2` :

```
Dataset<Row> sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM global_temp.records");
sqlDF.show();
```

will I be able to visualize `sqlDF` in the master node `VM2`?
Otherwise how to do this exercise of accessing datasets remotely?

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to ask. Spark context is available on all workers, dataset is split between executors and in case there is terminal action such as `collect`, which `SELECT * FROM global_temp.records` essentially is, all datasets are pulled to driver.

Comment: so one dataset that i put in one node is accessible through sparksession to another ? (if they are worker and master nodes) ? (dataset is shared you mean not split among all workers and master nodes) ? and so the above procedure as described by my question will then work right ?

Comment: You can't put a dataset into specific node with Spark, how are you planning to do that? You run transformations on `SparkContext` and Spark is the one deciding which part of whole execution plan is going onto which executor. I think you go something wrong about fundamentals of Spark.

Comment: I open the `spark-shell` on the worker node, and i just create  a `globalTempView` in the worker Node, and then i create my spark application, connect it to the master and read the `globalTempView` (using the shared `spark session` among workers and master) in order to read and display the dataset : that's how i plan to do it !

Comment: Are you starting two different spark jobs and creating two different spark contexts on two nodes?

Comment: No, i start one application (driver) on the master node (but i created another sparksession (on the worker) in a previous step to define the globalTempView to which i want to access through the master and the newly created application)

Comment: I'm afraid that it's not possible to access Spark context from completely separate application. There is maybe a dirty hack, but I don't think Spark is designed to be used that way.

Comment: then necessarly the datasets should be on the node from where we initiate the spark application ? how to do if HDFS (on a different node) contains the datasets and needs to be accessed from the master node ? spark sql (or hive in the case of the global tables) requires the same spark session to be accessed ?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely are trying to use spark not like it was designed.

There are no needs to use different spark sessions on different nodes. Spark works with distributed data structures. It means you don't need to manage your data location manually. You can use both of your datasets from different nodes in one spark application.

Comment: "You can use both of your datasets from different nodes in one spark application." does it mean the only way i could play with the data with the 2 nodes is by duplicating the datasets over the 2 nodes (master and slave) ?

Comment: No. It won't be duplicated. One part of data will be processing on first node and other part on second node. I recommend you to read more about spark data structures and how distributed computation work https://techvidvan.com/tutorials/apache-spark-rdd/

Comment: no i mean when you read the dataset to be processed by the application, the dataset should be present on both nodes (duplicated) (e.g sc.textFile("path") : the dataset file having the path "path" should be both on node 1 and node 2 in order for the application to process it over the two nodes later on through the code right ?

Comment: It is not necessary. Do you use spark with any distributed file system (HDFS, S3 etc)?

Comment: for now no HDFS or S3, explain more this point pls

Comment: Spark can run with local file system if it is using in standalone mode. If you want to use spark in cluster mode you need to use any distributed file system (HDFS, S3 etc) and resource manager (YARN, Mesos etc). It will provides you API to distributed storing and processing of your files. Spark docs has a lot of information about it https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html

Comment: Hadoop and Yarn / Mesos should be installed on a seperated node ?

Comment: No, it works on your cluster

Comment: yes, but where to install it first, Hadoop / HDFS should be installed on the master node right ?

Comment: Please use Hadoop / HDFS docs. It contains full info about installation.